# Haskell type signature pi

Tags: haskell, types, pi, approximation

I am very new to Haskell and functional programming.

I want to approximate pi with a programm. My code works but only without the type-signature.
Yet the task is to write a list-comprehension that fits the given type-signature so I probably have to change sth in my list-comprehension.

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double

pi_approx n = sqrt (6 * (sum [1 / x^2 | x <- [1..n]]))
```

Comment: In the future you might get better responses if you made your title a question. People skimming won't know your problem from your title. Although in this case you did get a very complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for that information!

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this does not work with the signature `Int -> Double` is because functions like [**`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-42-) and [**`sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt) require that the operand(s) and the result all have the same type.

This thus means that if `n` is an `Int`, then `x` in `x <- [1..n]` is also an `Int`, and since the type signature of `(^)` is [**`(^) :: (^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-94-), it means that `x ^ 2` has the same type as `x`, and this is thus an `Int` as well.

The problem that now arises is that [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) requires the type to a member of the `Fractional` typeclass, and an `Int` is is not `Fractional`.

We can make use of [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to convert a value from a type that is a member of the `Integral` typeclass to value with a type that is a member of the `Num` typeclass.

We thus can fix this problem with:

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double
pi_approx n = sqrt (6 * (sum [1 / fromIntegral (x^2) | x <- [1..n]]))
```

if `x` can be large, it makes sense, as [@dfeuer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67349763/haskell-type-signature-pi/67349840?noredirect=1#comment119045868_67349840), to convert `x` to a double before calculating the square:

```
pi_approx :: Int -> Double
pi_approx n = sqrt (6 * (sum [1 / fromIntegral x^2 | x <- [1..n]]))
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude> pi_approx 1
2.449489742783178
Prelude> pi_approx 2
2.7386127875258306
Prelude> pi_approx 10
3.04936163598207
Prelude> pi_approx 20
3.094669524113704
Prelude> pi_approx 100
3.1320765318091053
Prelude> pi_approx 200
3.136826306330968
Prelude> pi_approx 1000
3.1406380562059946
```

Comment: I'd go for `fromIntegral x ^ 2` to develop good habits. `fromIntegral (x^2)` will overflow much sooner, especially on a 32-bit build.

Comment: In trying to diagnose problems like these in the future it can be helpful to open ghci, run your code without the type signature, and then see what the type of the answer is. Then you can see what type is being assigned to your code. Also, the type signature doesn't "force" the type. `Prelude> pi_approx n = sqrt (6 * (sum [1 / x^2 | x <- [1..n]])) 
Prelude> :t (pi_approx 3)
(pi_approx 3) :: (Floating a, Enum a) => a`